# MuiCssBaseline override background image with opacity

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

i have been to apply a background image to my demo app writed with react, next and material-ui.
In my _app.js I have this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import theme from '../components/theme';

export default function App({Component, pageProps}) {
    return( 
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

I have a simple theme.js:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

// Create a theme instance.
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiCssBaseline: {
            "@global": {
                body: {
                    backgroundImage: "url(images/sfondo.jpg)",
                    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                    backgroundPosition: "center center",
                    backgroundSize: "cover",
                    backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
                    height: "100%",
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In this mode I can see the background image. It's works fine.
If I add in the theme.js

`opacity: 0.25`

this is applied at all content of page but not at background image.

I suppose the I need to use a "::before" and z-index property, but I don't know how apply this.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import theme from '../components/theme';

export default function App({Component, pageProps}) {
    return( 
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className="customBg">
        <Component {...pageProps} />
       </div>
        </ThemeProvider>
    )
}
```

then:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiCssBaseline: {
            "@global": {
                '.customBg': {
                    position: relative;
                    overflow: hidden;
                },
                '.customBg::before': {
                    content: ' ';
                    display: block;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 0;
                    top: 0;
                    width: 100 % ;
                    height: 100 % ;
                    zIndex: 1;
                    opacity: 0.6;
                    backgroundImage: "url(images/sfondo.jpg)",
                    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                    backgroundPosition: "center center",
                    backgroundSize: "cover",
                    backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
                    height: "100%",
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```